# RabbitMQ REST HTTP JSON payload

Tags: json, rest, rabbitmq

I am trying to use RabbitMQ HTTP REST client to publish messages into the queue. I am using the following url and request

http://xxxx/api/exchanges/xxxx/exc.notif/publish

```
{
 "routing_key":"routing.key",
  "payload":{

  },
 "payload_encoding":"string",
 "properties":{
   "headers":{
     "notif_d":"TEST",
     "notif_k": ["example1", "example2"],
     "userModTime":"timestamp"
   }
 }
}
```

And getting back from the rabbit the following response:

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"payload_not_string"}
```

I have just one header set:

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

I was trying to set the

```
"payload_encoding":"base64",
```

but it didn't help. I am new to rabbit any response is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with

```
{
"properties": {
"content-type": "application/json"
},
"routing_key": "testKey",
"payload": "1234",
"payload_encoding": "string"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My challenge is that I would like to have JSON in the payload. Something similar

"payload" : {
"nos":["test"],
"parameters":{"var2":"val2","var1":"val1"},
"exception":"test-excpetion"
}

I tried String and escapes but still no joy.

Comment: You helped me a lot. just escaped the json properly and its working fine. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Working example. We need simple to escape doublequotes.
It is important that the colon is outside of the quotes, as this causes inexplicable errors.

```
{
    "properties": {},
    "routing_key": "q_testing",
    "payload": "{
        \"message\": \"message from terminal\"
    }",
    "payload_encoding": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to send content-type using underscore "_" instead of dash.

See [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/212#issuecomment-222332128) for list of valid properties.
See [RabbitMQ Management HTTP API](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/) for some examples.

To publish a json message using curl to rabbit exchange:

```sh
curl -i -u guest:guest -XPOST --data '{"properties":\
{"content_type":"application/json"}, \
"routing_key":"", \
"payload":"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}",\
"payload_encoding":"string"}' \
"http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/exchange_name/publish"
```

content_type is written using **underscore**, routing_key is empty to send a message to exchange, not to particular queue.

Answer (score 1):

To use a JSON formatted payload you have to encode it in base64 and use the `"payload_encoding": "base64"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is indeed setting `payload_encoding` to `base64`. While this was already answered above, here is a complete `curl` example:

```bash
json='{"type": "earl-grey", "strength": 7, "milk": true}'
amqp_host=amqp.improbability.cloud
amqp_username=slarti
amqp_password=bartfast
amqp_vhost=heart-of-gold
amqp_exchange=food.dispenser
amqp_queue=tea-requests
amqp_message_id=$(uuid)
amqp_delivery_mode=2
payload=$(echo -n $json | base64 -w0)
authorization=$(echo -n "${amqp_username}:${amqp_password}" | base64 -w0)

curl https://${amqp_host}/api/exchanges/${amqp_vhost}/${amqp_exchange}/publish   \
  -H "authorization: Basic ${authorization}" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  --data @- <<EOF
{
  "properties": {
    "message_id":"${amqp_message_id}",
    "delivery_mode": ${amqp_delivery_mode}
  },
  "routing_key": "${amqp_queue}",
  "payload_encoding":"base64",
  "payload": "${payload}"
}
EOF
```

The rendering of the above with shell variables expanded:

```bash
curl https://amqp.improbability.cloud/api/exchanges/heart-of-gold/food.dispenser/publish 
  -H "authorization: Basic c2xhcnRpOmJhcnRmYXN0" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
  --data @- <<EOF
{
  "properties": {
    "message_id":"eb28ad00-f86f-11ed-9e7f-00155d591867",
    "delivery_mode": 2
  },
  "routing_key": "tea-requests",
  "payload_encoding":"base64",
  "payload": "eyJ0eXBlIjogImVhcmwtZ3JleSIsICJzdHJlbmd0aCI6IDcsICJtaWxrIjogdHJ1ZX0="
}
EOF
```

Result:

```
=> {"routed":true}
```