# Cryptic "Response code 400 (Bad Request)" message from rabbitmq /publish

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm getting this cryptic "Response code 400 (Bad Request)" error message when I try to publish a message to rabbitmq. This is what my request looks like:

```
            got.post(`https://rabbit.somedomain.com/api/exchanges/%2F/${exchange}/publish`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('myusername:password').toString('base64'),
                },
                json: {
                    properties: {},
                    routing_key,
                    payload: 'test',
                    payload_encoding: 'string'
                },
                timeout: 10000,
                responseType: 'json',
            }).then(response => {
                if (Number(response.statusCode) !== 200) {
                    throw new Error(response);
                }
                console.log('success');
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('failed to publish message:', err);
            });
```

As you'd expect, this request works perfectly using Postman. I get the success response:

```
{
    "routed": true
}
```

More so, the problem appears specific to the `/publish` endpoint. For instance I don't get this error from the `/bindings` or `/exchanges` endpoints. Normally the error responses are in the form `{"error":"bad_request","reason":"whatever_is_wrong"}` so at least I'd be able to debug, but not the case here. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905126/rabbitmq-rest-http-json-payload) is the closest to this problem that I've found but the suggestions there don't solve my problem. I'm doing this in a nodejs server by the way. Pretty stumped here, I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: On a side node , consider using AMQP client it will be much faster and give you a higher through put

Comment: Are you saying that the response body is empty, and the HTTP status code is 400; or that the response body is the actual string "Response code 400 (Bad Request)"?

Comment: @IMSoP I mean that the response comes back with a 400 status code, and the body contains the cryptic error message.